# Null pointer on a split() that shouldn't be reached

Tags: javafx, file-io, while-loop, split, bufferedreader

So I'm reading a list of bikeParts from a .txt file. That part works fine. The trouble is I have a while loop for my buffered reader that is supposed to be checking if the next line is empty. The program loops through every aprt in the .txt file, but then tries to read an extra "null" line. I'm confused as to why the program is not exiting the while loop.

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;

public class Main extends Application {
    public static String read(String fileName) {
        String success="success";
        String nope="not found";
        String IO="could not read file";

        File file = new File(fileName);
        String line = null;
        String[] fileNamer = fileName.split(".txt");
        String houseName = fileNamer[0].toString();
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            ArrayList<BikeParts> partList = new ArrayList<>();

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { //the while loop in question
                line = br.readLine();
                String[] elements = line.split(",");  //null pointer on this line
                partList.add(new BikeParts(elements[0], (elements[1]), Double.parseDouble(elements[2]),
                        Double.parseDouble(elements[3]), Boolean.parseBoolean(elements[4]), Integer.parseInt(elements[5])));
            }//BikeParts is a constructor for each part on the .txt file. makes a part object out of partName, partNumber, listPrice, salesPrice, onSale, and quantity
            Warehouse house = new Warehouse(houseName, partList);  //partList is the ArrayList of parts that is contained within the Warehouse that was just created by the user
            return success;  //debug return statement
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return nope;  //debug return statement
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return IO;  //debug return statement
        }
    }

    public void display() {

    }

    public void newPart(BikeParts p) {
        MainWarehouse.add(p);
    }

    public void sortMainByName(MainWarehouse houseName) {


    }

    public void sortByNumber() {

    }

    public void addVan(String vanName, ArrayList<BikeParts> invName) {
        //Vans.Vans(vanName,invName);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("GUI.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 800, 800));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

the .txt file:

```
26inTube,1234567891,7.00,5.58,true,35
10spFrontDerailer,1234567897,41.00,31.50,true,10
seatPost,1234567892,17.00,1.23,true,5
700-25SwhalbeTire,1234567895,51.00,40.50,true,10
carbonHandleBars42cm,1234567893,47.00,5.58,true,3
10spRearDerailuer,1234567896,82.00,70.50,true,10
11spFrontDerailuer,1234567899,61.00,50.50,true,10
WTB_saddle,1234567890,33.00,25.58,false,15
mensBibsMedium,1234567900,110.00,99.00,false,4
womensHelmetSmall,1234567901,130.00,79.00,false,4
spdPedals,1234567902,62.31,79.00,true,4
700-23SwhalbeTire,1234567894,51.00,40.50,true,10
timePedals,1234567903,102.31,89.00,false,4
frogPedalsTitanium,1234567904,142.31,130.00,false,4
11spRearDerailuer,1234567898,97.00,80.50,true,10
carbonWheelSet,1234567905,542.31,480.00,false,4
mountainFork29,1234567912,223.00,195.00,false,4
lynskeyTitaniumFrame265Med,1234567906,2542.99,1880.00,false,2
grr,1234567907,4567.89,3456.78,false,2
zarminComputer,1234567908,543.21,480.00,false,2
womensBibsMedium,1234567909,110.00,99.00,false,4
womensJacketMedium,1234567911,120.00,95.00,false,4
mensJacketMedium,1234567910,120.00,95.00,false,4
```

This is a .FXML project, so there are more classes, but this is currently the only one I have any problems with. Why is it going through that while loop? I ran the program in debug mode and on the final run through, line = null, which causes the null pointer on the split call. But it shouldn't get to that split()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well without compiling your code I am 99.9% sure that the error is on second readLine() call, your while condition is `(line = br.readLine()) != null` which means you are reading a line and you assigned it to the variable line and after that you are checking if the line is null. After that for some reason you are reading for the nextLine() and you '**discard**' the previous line. So if you read the last line from your txt file the while condition will be true and you will read again from file setting the `line = null`  so trying to split a null String will give you an NullPointerExpection

In order to fix your problem just remove the second readLine() call

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { 
    String[] elements = line.split(",");  
    partList.add(new BikeParts(elements[0], (elements[1]), Double.parseDouble(elements[2]),
            Double.parseDouble(elements[3]), Boolean.parseBoolean(elements[4]), Integer.parseInt(elements[5])));
}
```

Comment: mate you're a lifesaver, thank you so much. that did it

Comment: Glad to help, we tend to believe our code works as we expect so for future problems like that just try to insert a print statement on each line to see what's really happening

Comment: thats what i was trying to with the debug mode, i just didnt make the connection that i was discarding the first line. I guess i actually didnt know the assignment in the while statement stuck, i thought it was just a condition test